# Text area doesn't seem to be working

Tags: java, textarea

I am try to create a text area that will display a list of scores. For some reason though, the text area only expands when someone types in it, and the user should not even be allowed to type in it. I thought i wrote in the code for it properly but for some reason it doesn't seem to work. The "hello" phrase I appended isn't even displaying in the text area. Can anyone provide some advice:

```
    public HighScores() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException{
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setSize(400,200);
    frame.add(main);
    GridBagConstraints g = new GridBagConstraints();
    g.insets = new Insets(10,10,10,10);
    g.gridx = 0;
    g.gridy = 0;
    main.add(highscorespanel, g);
    highscorespanel.add(highscores);
    g.gridx = 0;
    g.gridy = 1;
    main.add(textareapanel, g);
    Color c = textareapanel.getBackground();
    textareapanel.setBackground(c);
    textareapanel.add(ta);
    ta = new JTextArea ();
    ta.setVisible(true);
    ta.setEnabled(true);
    ta.setEditable(false);

    ta.append("hello");
    JScrollPane sp = new JScrollPane(ta);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("src/BattleShip/scores.txt"));
    String namescore = br.readLine();
    while(namescore!=null){
        ta.append("\t"+namescore);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Im almost sure you don't need the answer anymore but you need to move your line "textareapanel.add(ta);" to some point after you initialize ta.

```
ta = new JTextArea();
textareapanel.add(ta);
ta.setVisible(true);
ta.setEnabled(true);
ta.setEditable(false);
```

**EDIT**:

At a second look you want a JScrollPane for your JTextArea so you code should be like this:

```
JTextArea ta = new JTextArea();
ta.setVisible(true);
ta.setEnabled(true);
ta.setEditable(false);

JScrollPane sp = new JScrollPane(ta);
textareapanel.add(sp);
```